# Botão Toogle , com ação em html

Tags: html, css

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site , e gostaria de criar um botão "Mostrar Mais" quando clicado ira mostrar um texto , mas a lista que estará em baixo ira descer , como exemplificado na imagem , qual o método mas simples e pratico para fazer ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é para descer o que está abaixo? É para o de cima ficar por cima do que está abaixo?

Answer (score 1):

Fiz esse modelo só com CSS, é bem simples, mas é só para fins didáticos e para você entender melhor o técnica.

Aqui tem um `label` com um `for` para o `input checkbox` que quando estiver `:checked` vai mostrar o conteúdo. Só que esse `input` fica escondido e o `label` faz o papel do botão. Veja o Snippet pra entender melhor.

```css
.wrapper {
    padding: 8px 24px 24px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin: 16px;
}
a, label {
    color: orangered;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hide {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .hide {
    display: block
}
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) ~ .hide {
    display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Título</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn-a">
    <label for="btn-a">Mostrar Mais</label>
    <div class="hide">
    <h4>Aqui meu conteúdo.</h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, asperiores?
    </div>
</div>
<br clear="all">
<div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Título</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn-b">
    <label for="btn-b">Mostrar Mais</label>
    <div class="hide">
    <h4>Aqui meu conteúdo.</h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, asperiores?
    </div>
</div>
```

Se precisar que seja em JavaScript eu te passo um modelo, mas acho desnecessário...